# Can tensorflow models be trained on images with larger resolution?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

Need help on understanding whether Tensorflow models can be trained on larger resolutions like 4K resolution. I tried, but the training is not getting commenced, I hope because of some memory issue. Has anyone worked on the same?

Comment: what errors do you get? the size of the image shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Igna, I am not able to start the training for the model as said by Matias below, for the same reason of too much large feature vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory you can, there are no limitations on TensorFlow that prevent you from doing this.

But in practice, the limitation is GPU or system RAM. A 3840x2160 (4K) single-channel floating point feature map is around 32 MB of RAM, and generally a convolutional network uses multiple feature maps at each layer, from 96 to 512. For example, 128 4K feature maps would need around 1 GB of RAM, and then training using batches and keeping intermediate results for gradient computation, would require too much RAM.

If you look at input shapes to common ImageNet-trained neural networks, sizes are usually 224x224, 256x256, and the biggest I have seen is 600x600 for object detection networks like SSD and Faster R-CNN. These sizes are very far from a full 4K image.

TLDR. You should downscale your images to a manageable size.

Comment: Yes. I am facing the same issue. That the models are not getting initialized for training. Thank you for your suggestion. But, the use case I am handling does not suggest reducing the inputs, in order to preserve much detailed information.